# MySQL query WHERE x and if set y

Tags: mysql

I've been working on a project at work and I need data from two tables. I'm no expert on MySQL queries, but I got this far:

```
SELECT *
FROM `p_list` AS pl
JOIN `employee` AS em
WHERE em.id =10
AND pl.employee_id =10
```

It works fine when there is a pl.employee_id, but returns o result where there isn't. It makes sense, but I don't know how i can get it to return where em.id=10 and if pl.employee_id is set.

I'm about to give up and just run two queries and let PHP do the dirty work.

Comment: There must be a typo in your second paragraph as it's contradictory...?

Comment: I believe both answers are incorrect... by using a LEFT JOIN, but putting an absolute WHERE clause on the EM.ID, that basically creates a normal INNER JOIN.  So, the real question.. Do you want all "P_LIST" records regardless of an employee match?  Or do you really just want data for specific employee... they can't be both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT *
FROM   `p_list` AS pl
       LEFT JOIN `employee` AS em
          ON em.id = pl.employee_ID
WHERE  em.id = 10
```

Basically, what you are doing now is an `INNER JOIN`. `INNER JOIN` is different from `LEFT JOIN` (*which is what you need*). `INNER JOIN` only returns result if a record specified in the join condition has atleast one match on the other table. `LEFT JOIN`, *on the other hand*, returns all rows specified on the *LEFT* table whether it has a match or none match on the other table.

Comment: by adding the WHERE clause, you basically cancelled out your LEFT JOIN by QUALIFYING the WHERE EM.ID = 10.  I commented in his question to clarify what he ACTUALLY wants.

Comment: @DRapp I'm not really sure on what you mean. Because as far as my understanding goes on the question he only wants to select `em.id = 10` whether it has a match or no match on the `employee` table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a left join to do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `p_list` AS pl
LEFT JOIN `employee` AS em ON em.id = pl.employee_id
WHERE em.id =10
```